# Bibliographies when using subfiles

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, conditionals, subfiles

I am writing my Ph.D. thesis in XeLaTeX with Biblatex, and there are times when I need to compile individual chapters, and times when I need to compile the entire document, so I use subfiles, which works wonderfully. However, in each of these chapters I have a `\printbibliography` command, which I would like to turn off when compiling the final document, so that only the `\printbibliography` command is run in the mainfile.

The file structure is something like:

`Main.tex`:

```
\usepackage{subfiles, biblatex}
\begin{document}

\subfile{Chapter1.tex}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

`Chapter1.tex`:

```
\documentclass[Main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\cite{Someguy1981}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From `subfiles.sty` the `\subfile` command is defined as:

```
\newcommand\subfile[1]{\begingroup\skip@preamble\input{#1}\endgroup}
```

So it is straightforward to hook in some code to locally redefine `\printbibliography` to do nothing. For an example add the following to the preamble of the main file:

```
\makeatletter

\newrobustcmd*{\nobibliography}{%
  \@ifnextchar[%]
    {\blx@nobibliography}
    {\blx@nobibliography[]}}

\def\blx@nobibliography[#1]{}

\appto{\skip@preamble}{\let\printbibliography\nobibliography}

\makeatother
```

Note that `biblatex` makes bibliographic data available via citation commands. So unless you want to view the bibliography entries outside the main file, the subfiles need not invoke `\printbibliography`.

Comment: I have tested this and it works perfectly.

Comment: This stuff goes in the main file or in the subfile?

Does it works with standard LaTeX or has something XeLaTeX specific?

Comment: It appears that this solution no longer works due to internal refactoring of the subfiles package.

Answer (score 11):

I also used Audrey's approach (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107111/85983) for a while, but I got annoyed of having to write `\printbibliography` at the end of each subfile. Now I'm using the following Latex Hooks in the preamble of my main file:

```
%%% Default start and end for each subfile
\AtBeginDocument{%
}

\AtEndDocument{%
    \printbibliography
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \newpage
    \printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name=Acronyms]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since version 2.0 of subfiles, one can also use the condition macro `\ifSubfilesClassLoaded{}{}` to do something similar as Audrey's approach (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107111/85983).

With my setup, a MWE is as follows:

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{subfiles} % must be last usepackage

\providecommand{\topdir}{.}
\addglobalbib{\topdir/references.bib} % topdir is needed here so that
                                      % we can resolve the path in the subfile
                                      % correctly. There we re-define the
                                      % topdir macro to the location of the
                                      % bib file.

\begin{document}
\subfile{dir/sub}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]{}
\end{document}
```

**sub.tex**

```
\providecommand{\topdir}{..} % reset all paths to location of main.tex
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
% some content with citations

\ifSubfilesClassLoaded{%
    \printbibliography{}
}{} % we have no 'else' action
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks heaps. I'm using TexStudio. Using the command `\topdir` breaks the inbuilt referencing suggestions by TexStudio, and reverting to `\addglobalbib{./references.bib}` conversely breaks subfile compiling. Anyway to get both working? (TexStudio 4.6.3)

Answer (score 3):

Borrowing [a post on this Latex Community thread](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=10320), you can define your `\printbibliography` command in the preamble and then un-define it in the main document. Your main file will then contain its own call to `\bibliography{}` and `\biblographystyle`.

Something like:

**Main.tex**

```
\usepackage{subfiles, biblatex}
\newcommand{\dobib}{ % Define the command
    \bibliographystyle{acm}
    \bibliography{../../references} % Place the path relative to the subfile here
}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\dobib}{} % Un-define the command

    \subfile{Chapter1.tex}

    \bibliographystyle{acm}
    \bibliography{../references} % Place the path relative to the main file here
\end{document}
```

**Chapter1.tex**

```
\documentclass[Main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
    According to SomeGuy \cite{Someguy1981} pigs can fly.

    \dobib
\end{document}
```

This works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach could be to distinguish between the subfiles and the main file by their jobname. Say your main file is called `Thesis.tex`, then the jobname is normally `Thesis` and you can test

```
\IfEq{\jobname}{\detokenize{Thesis}}{}{%
    \AtEndDocument{%
        \printbibliography%
    }
}
```

this will insert a bibliography at the end of the subfiles and do nothing in your main file.

*(if possible use this before `\usepackage{biblatex}`, otherwise it might cause a warning, see [undefined references warning for \AtEndDocument{\printbibliography}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/371814/36296))*