# Package biblatex and subfile not working in subfiles

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, texmaker, subfiles

I am trying to use `biber` and package `subfile`. 
Thank to the community I manage to make it run in the main file. See here:
[Bibliographies when using subfiles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107064/bibliographies-when-using-subfiles)

The file `bbl` is not created in the folder where I have my subfile and I get the error:

```
 ! Package biblatex Error: File '05-Introduction.bbl' not created by biblatex.
See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.3 \begin{document}
This file was apparently not created by biblatex. Rename it or
move it to a location were TeX will not find it. If this error
persists, consider redefining \blxauxsuffix.See the biblatex
manual for details.
```

I have to precise that I use subfile with the following structure

```
./main/main.tex
./tex/05-Introduction.tex
./biblio/biblio.bib
./mystyle.sty
```

I am running window 7 64bit with MiKTeX 2.9, TeXmaker 4, jabref 2.9
Texmaker and bib database are in UTF8.

I already spent 1.5 day to make it work and it is the last bit that is still missing.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. What is `mystyle.sty`? You can use package `filecontents` to add an external file in your MWE.