# bibtex references in subfile

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, subfiles

I have a folder `Report`, that contains the file `Report.tex` and the subfolder `References`, which contains the files `ref.tex` and `references.bib`. In `ref.tex` I can reference a citation of `references.bib`. However, when in `Report.tex` it is not recongized (displayed as `[?]`). Does anyone know how I can solve this?

These are the files:

- `Report.tex:`

  ```
  \documentclass{book}
  \usepackage{subfiles}

  \begin{document}
  \subfile{References/ref.tex}
  \end{document}
  ```
- `ref.tex`:

  ```
  \documentclass[../Report.tex]{subfiles}

  \begin{document}
  \chapter{References}\label{chapter:references} Please just be a nice citation: \cite{fasshauer2011positive}.
  \bibliography{references}  \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
  \end{document}
  ```
- `references.bib`

  ```
  @article{fasshauer2011positive,
     title={Positive definite kernels: past, present and future},
     author={Fasshauer, Gregory E},  
     journal={Dolomite Research Notes on Approximation},
     volume={4},  
     pages={21--63},
     year={2011}
  }
  ```

I though I ran all the necessary files in latex/bibtex, as the references is displayed as "[1]" in `ref.tex`, but it still doesn't show up in `Report.tex`.

Comment: I have re-tagged your question (it is not really about  `biblatex`, you use standard BibTeX) and made the markup a bit easier on the eye (you should use the code button to format source code, not the quotation button). I suspect this has something to do with which files one needs BibTeX to compile. Maybe [Handle .bib in subfiles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/217517/35864) can help you.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I consecutively run: `references.bib` in `BibTeX`, `ref.tex` in `pdfLaTeX`,`BibTeX` and `pdfLaTeX`, which works, then I run `Report.tex` as well in `pdfLaTeX`,`BibTeX` and `pdfLaTeX`, which does not work :(

Comment: I can't test your example right now, but it might be a problem with file paths and needed files. Maybe you can move the files to the same directory? Also, do you really need to use `subfiles` that is, do you have to be able to compile `ref.tex` on its own, or would you be fine with standard `\input`/`\include`?

Comment: @moewe, thanks! I do need subfiles (I am working on my thesis, so I want to be able to write each chapter seperately), by the file `ref.tex` was unnecessary. It works now, I'll write an answer, in case it'll help anyone else.

Comment: Ah, I see, maybe you should have a look at `\includeonly` and friends ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to moewe, I now have it working. Changing `Report.tex` into

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}
This is a reference: \cite{fasshauer2011positive}.

\bibliography{References/references}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

\end{document}
```

and removing `ref.tex` did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, deleted you temporary files especially these two files .aux, .bbl.
These temporary files you will get in the same folder where you have saved your .tex file and .bib file.
Then you should insert \usepackage{natbib} in your .tex file. Then compiled as a LaTex, then complied BibTeX, then compiled LaTex then dvi>ps, then ps>pdf. I think it will work. Best of luck!

Comment: There is no need here for `natbib` since BibTeX can handle things on their own, nor does the question request that (even of a solution).

Comment: Indeed, plus I came up with the solution 4 days short of a year ago.