# bibtex when using subfiles package

Tags: bibtex, subfiles

### Edit:

This question is actually a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/217517/122509). It's solution worked for me.

---

Basically, I want to do what [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107064/bibliographies-when-using-subfiles) is doing, but using `bibtex` instead of `biblatex`.

To summarize what it's doing there, I want a single `.bib` files to store the bibliography entries for an entire document. When I run a section file (ie. not the `main.tex`), it cannot find the `Sources.bib` and so fails to make the reference. If I run `main.tex` though, the reference that is inside the section file resolves perfectly fine.

For a minimum working example (it doesn't run correctly, but it gives you the idea), see below.

So I have the following file structure:

```
project_dir
|    main.tex
|    background.tex
|    Sources.bib
```

Inside `main.tex`, I have:

```
%%%% main.tex %%%
\documentclass[10pt]{ClemsonThesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}
% blah blah blah

\subfile{background.tex}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Sources}
\end{document}
```

---

```
%%% background.tex %%%
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

%blah blah blah
Here's some random text I have in a few paragraphs. Here's a citation for referencing an external resource: \cite{McCormack2012}.

\end{document}
```

---

```
%%% Sources.bib %%%
@Inbook{McCormack2012,
author="McCormack, Percival",
title="The Vortex",
bookTitle="Vortex, Molecular Spin and Nanovorticity: An Introduction",
year="2012",
publisher="Springer New York",
address="New York, NY",
pages="1--65",
abstract="The first notable works on fluid motions appeared in the early seventeenth century. Descartes in his ``Principia Philosophiae'' (1644) considered that space was filled with frictional vortices, so that the planets are carried along by the vortex motions. Vortices had fascinated mankind for many centuries before Descartes. It was considered that life had started in the water of the primeval vortex -- in whirlwinds and whirlpools.",
isbn="978-1-4614-0257-2",
doi="10.1007/978-1-4614-0257-2_1",
url="https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4614-0257-2_1"
}
```

Using the files below, if I compile `background.tex`, the bibtex reference fails. If I run `main.tex`, the bibtex reference that is in `background.tex` resolves perfectly fine.

I've tried adding `\bibliography{Sources}` to the end of the `background.tex` file, but got nothing.

Comment: Look at the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217517/handle-bib-in-subfiles). This has worked for me.

Comment: Awesome! That worked for me.

Comment: @moewe Yes... That question has already been linked in my edited question and kristjan's comment above.

Comment: I know, that's why I 'formally' voted to close it as a duplicate. Or do you think it makes sense to keep the question open and add an answer?

Comment: Ah, gotcha. No, I think officially marking it as a duplicate makes sense. I didn't realize there was a 'formal' way to vote on closing the question.