# how to compile subfiles with bibtex citations?

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, subfiles

Consider the following `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\subfile{chapter1.tex}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Here is `chapter1.tex`:

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\chapter{My Title}
\cite{key}   % the problem
\end{document}
```

Compiling `main.tex` with pdflatex bibtex pdflatex pdflatex and all is good. But a primary goal of `subfiles` is to allow subfile compilation, and I cannot figure out how to compile `chapter1.tex` in this way with the citation defined.

Can someone please post the exact changes that will allow this (with bibtex)?  The "hints" in the `subfiles` documentation are not enough for me.  (I tried `\subfix` without luck.)

Comment: Somehow the contents of your main document and `chapter1.tex` are identical. In particular `chapter1.tex` has `\subfile{chapter1.tex}`, which to me looks like an infinite loop waiting to happen. If you really use `\jobname` in your actual document that could be an issue as that command may or may not be different for compilation of the main file and the subfile (but of course that `\jobname` may only be here for the MWE). Can you show us the `.log` and (probably more importantly here) `.blg` file of the subfile compilation. Do you use a more complex folder structure in your real-world example?

Comment: @moewe Example fixed.  And yes, the use of `\jobname` is just for a MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we run `bibtex chapter1` (after having run `pdflatex chapter1`) we get

> ```
> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.7380 64-bit)
> The top-level auxiliary file: chapter1.aux
> I found no \bibdata command---while reading file chapter1.aux
> I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file chapter1.aux
> ```

so BibTeX complains about not knowing which style to take and which `.bib` file to access. Essentially that is because `chapter1.tex` has neither a `\bibliographystyle`
call to set the bibliography style, nor a `\bibliography` call to tell BibTeX which `.bib` file to use. The subfile can read the preamble of its parent, but not the document body, so it never gets to see the `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` and `\bibliography{\jobname}` in `main.tex`.

We need a way to tell BibTeX about the style and the `.bib` file.

For the bibliography style that is simple, because `\bibliographystyle` may be used in the preamble, so you could just make your `main.tex` read

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{subfiles}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\begin{document}
\subfile{chapter1.tex}

\bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{document}
```

But that still leaves `chapter1.tex` unaware of `\bibliography`. Unfortunately, it is not possible to simply move `\bibliography` into the preamble, because (with BibTeX) `\bibliography` must be used at the place where the bibliography is printed.

You need a `\bibliography` call in `chapter1.tex` if you want to compile the file separately with working citations. But just adding `\bibliography{mybibfile}` to `chapter1.tex` will lead to two bibliographies (and/or an error) in `main.tex`. Ideally, we'd find a way to check if we are compiling the subfile `chapter1.tex` on its own or in the context of the full file `main.tex`. I didn't find an official check for that in the documentation, but think it would be a useful addition, so I had to roll my own test that replicates `\@ifclassloaded`: If `chapter1.tex` is compiled on its own, the class will be `subfiles`, if it is compiled in the context of `main.tex` the class is different.

So here we are: `\subfilesbibliography` creates a bibliography when the file is compiled on its own, but not when it is compiled in the main document.

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{subfiles}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\makeatletter
% curse you, \@onlypreamble\@ifclassloaded
\newcommand*{\subfilesbibliography}[1]{%
 \expandafter\ifx\csname ver@subfiles.cls\endcsname\relax
   \expandafter\@secondoftwo
 \else
   \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi
  {\bibliography{#1}}
  {}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\subfile{chapter1.tex}

\bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{document}
```

`chapter1.tex`

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\chapter{My Title}
\cite{key}   % the problem

\subfilesbibliography{mybibfile}
\end{document}
```

Note that I used a fixed file name instead of `\jobname`, because the variable nature of `\jobname` would make things much more complicated.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/217517/35864

Comment: So ... is the "hint" in the subfiles documentation completely useless??

Comment: @Alan For the most part the hint is correct, but not particularly helpful for *your* use case. I guess the package author mainly tested the package in set-ups where the subfiles contained the `\bibliography` call (possibly with a package such as `bibunits` or `chapetrbib`), where your problem may not a arise. You can always open an issue at https://github.com/gsalzer/subfiles/issues and ask for clarification of the docs or for a more official interface for my implementation of `\subfilesbibliography`.

Comment: Issue opened at https://github.com/gsalzer/subfiles/issues/7