# Subfiles and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, subfiles

I've been trying to compile a multi-file project using `biblatex` and a .bib to handle the bibliography.

I have an output document, but all my citations appear undefined. I want to use the `\cite` command in each subfile, and print the whole bibliography at end of the main document.

I've followed these questions [Handle .bib in subfiles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217517/handle-bib-in-subfiles) and https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25506, but so far it hasn't worked.

I'd appreciate some help.

My main file looks like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{subfiles}

\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\subfile{Chapters/Introdution}

\end{document}
```

And the subfiles are like

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\addbibresource{\subfix{../references.bib}}

\begin{document}

A citation \cite{review1}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{cite}` is incompatible with `\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}`. Remove the `\usepackage{cite}`. If I try to compile a document similar to yours I get errors about `cite` being incompatible with `biblatex`. If I remove it I can compile both the main file and the included chapter just fine. Please tell us about how you compile each of your files, where it goes wrong exactly and if you get any errors or warnings in the `.log` and `.blg` files.