# Footnotes in Subfiles

Tags: biblatex, citing, subfiles

I am writing a large report in TeXshop and have decided to use subfiles for each chapter, and have created a `.bib` bibliography. However, now that I have separated the chapters into subfiles, the `footcites` I was using are no longer working (e.g. they put a footnote that says "Key", instead of with the actual citation).

Is there a way to only address the bibliography in my `main.tex`, rather than having to run through it in every subfile? Or am I better off switching to `\include` or just keeping everything in one long document?

```
%mybib.bib:
@book{Key,
  title={Nothing},
  author={Nobody},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

---

```
%chapter1.tex:
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
I would like a citation in the footnotes, so I try using \footcite{Key}
\end{document}
```

---

```
%main.tex:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
% !BIB TS-program = biber

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\subfile{Chapter1}  
\printbibliography
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl))?  Constructing ones with included files are an even more annoying than simple minimal working examples. So if you do that part of the hard work, others will be more likely to explore the problem and, ideally, suggest an answer to it.

Comment: If you use `biblatex` citations should work absolutely fine even if you split your document up into sub files. This makes me think something more is going on here. Please try and reproduce the problem in an MWE and make sure to also post the relevant warnings and errors from the log files.

Comment: As you can see in [Bibliographies when using subfiles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107064/35864) `subfiles` and `biblatex` can work together smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would need to use the power of `subfile` here, a simple `\include`/`\input` would probably be enough.

That said, the following MWE works mighty fine for me (obligatory `filecontents` warning: this document saved as `<file>.tex` will overwrite `<file>-sub1.tex`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-sub1.tex}
\documentclass[\jobname.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\section{Chapter 1}
I would like a citation in the footnotes, so I try using \footcite{geer}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\subfile{\jobname-sub1}  
\printbibliography
\nocite{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

Saved as `test.tex` I only needed to run `pdflatex test`, `biber test`, `pdflatex test`, `pdflatex test` and everything looked as expected.