# Citing a Reference (Website/Book/Article)

Tags: bibliographies

i've **thesis.tex**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

%----------------------%
% Inclusione pacchetti %
%----------------------%    
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[colorlinks, citecolor=black, filecolor=black, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=black] {hyperref}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subfig}


%--------------------%
% Stile della pagina %  
%--------------------%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{appendix}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}      
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{15mm} %margine pagina sinistro
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-15mm} %margine pagina destro

\begin{document}

\subfile{frontespizio}
\subfile{indice}
\subfile{introduzione}
\subfile{modelloClientServer}
\subfile{ProtocolHttp}
\subfile{ambitoApplicativo}
\subfile{conclusioni}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliografia}
\end{document}
```

in which,before the end of document I've included \bibliographystyle and /bibliography as suggested from various guides.
Created bib file named as **bibliografia**

```
@misc{
  pippo,
  title={site1},
  note={note1}
}
```

and then i try in any latex page to use the command \cite{pippo} (keyword).
Over leaf gives me a warning

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `pippo' on page 1 undefined on input line 8
```

where page 1 input line 8 is where I use the command \cite.
**How can I make it work ? I just need a bibliography but for websites.**

Comment: I edited the title of your question. I hope that I got it right. If not, then change it back.

Comment: Your code (minus all the \subfile) compiles for me just fine on Overleaf; and the citation shows up as well. Perhaps check that your bib file is named `bibliografia.bib` and not `bibliografia.BIB`!

Comment: thank you Manuel, you got it right. Lim just make my check my file and I'll make you know

Comment: The real reason here is because bibliographies in the "main" file are not handled in the "subfiles", which Federico is using: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107064/bibliographies-when-using-subfiles . Solved using a similar solution.

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone, Lim of overleaf support staff did a great job and fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Please read [this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) site before you post a new question. Here it is
>   explained how to provide a so-called **minimal working example**.

Since you just have two references, I recommend that you use a **manual bibliography** without the use of a database approach like `BiBLaTeX` or `BiBTeX` (outdated).

I prepared a simple setup with an article document class. If you want to use report or book then you should change the this line

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname} % section
```

into this

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\refname} % chapter
```

This code snipped includes the name of the reference (depending on the document language which is defined as an option to the `babel` package) to the table of contents (toc).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}

% load as last package
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\title{Simple Bibliography without BiBTeX or BiBLaTeX}
\author{Manuel Kuehner}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{Just a Random Section}
\blindtext

\section{Section with a Cite of a Website}

See \cite{bib:www:WebsiteOne} for more details.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}

\bibitem{bib:www:WebsiteOne}
Author, \emph{Title}, Internet Source, Last Checked: 2nd December 2016, \url{http://www.manuelkuehner.de/}

\end{thebibliography} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have much more references then you can have a look at my tutorials (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-Wl6F3zpJVwcDHK2rg9bDEEMjo70zp87) or the system `BiBLaTeX/Biber` in general.