# Undefined references warning for \AtEndDocument{\printbibliography}

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, warnings

Why does using `\AtEndDocument{\printbibliography}` cause the following warning?

> LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
>
> Package biblatex Warning: Please rerun LaTeX.

Just to clarify: The references are displayed exactly like they should be. I'm just wondering why this warning is issued.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\AtEndDocument{\printbibliography}

\begin{document}

    \cite{knuth:ct:c}

\end{document}
```

**Note:**

In case one wonders why this complicated syntax and not just using `\printbibliography` at the end of the document: This is just really convenient if used together with `subfiles`, see e.g. *[Bibliographies when using subfiles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107064/bibliographies-when-using-subfiles/358429#358429)*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`biblatex` does a lot of cleaning up (also with respect to `.aux` files and warnings) in the `\AtEndDocument` hook. You don't get the warning if you issue

```
\AtEndDocument{\printbibliography}
```

*before* loading `biblatex`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this simple solution and the explanation! You're the best!