# \ifstandalone command is not recognised

Tags: bibliographies, standalone

I have several subfiles and a main file as follows:

%subfile1

```
\documentclass[alpha-refs]{wiley-article}
\usepackage{standalone} 
.... 
\begin{document} 
some text
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{mybib} 
\end{document}
```

%subfile2

```
\documentclass[alpha-refs]{wiley-article}
\usepackage{standalone} 
.... 
\begin{document} 
some text
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{mybib} 
\end{document}
```

%main

```
\documentclass[alpha-refs]{wiley-article}
\usepackage[subpreambles=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}
.... 
\begin{document} 
some text
\section{1}
\subimport{sections/}{subfile1}
\section{2}
\subimport{sections/}{subfile2}
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

when I compile the subfiles I get the references since I included the bibliography in subfiles, and when I compile the main file, I get the references for each sections as well.
I want to see the references in the subfiles, but I ignore them in each section in the main file, and only show the references at the end of the main file. using `\ifstandalone ... \fi` around the `bibliography{}` in subfiles does not work since it does not recognize the command `\ifstandalone`, and gives the following error:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015)
The top-level auxiliary file: example.aux
The style file: rss.bst
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file subfile1.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "cite1"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "cite2"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "cite3"
(There was 1 error message)
```

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: I used an alternative solution from [Bibliographies when using subfiles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107064/bibliographies-when-using-subfiles), however, I appreciate any solutions using `\ifstandalone`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\ifstandalone` is set to true by the `standalone` *class* (used in subfiles) but to false by the `standalone` *package* (used in the main document). Your use case uses the `standalone` package in the subfiles as well. Try changing `\documentclass[alpha-refs]{wiley-article}
\usepackage{standalone}` to `\documentclass[alpha-refs,class=wiley-article]{standalone}` in the subfiles.