# How to show references after splitting Latex to several files

Tags: cross-referencing, subfiles

I am writing a paper by splitting it to several subfiles and editing each subfile once a time.

For each subfile, it has the code:

`\documentclass[../../main.tex]{subfiles}
 \begin{document}
 Content of the paper
 \end{document}`

(In the main file, I use packages
`\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amscd}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{mathrsfs}
 \usepackage{subfiles}`)

This enables me to compile the subfile and edit it. However, I met a problem that each time when I cite something in this subfile, it will not show up properly -- it just shows "[??]" (but it will show properly if I compile the main file).

My question is: is there any way that the subfile can show references properly (even better, it contains a list of reference at the end just as the main file)?

I know that I can add the .bib file to each folder where the subfile is kept, but this method is very inconvenient as I need to update my .bib file ocasionally.

Comment: are you using xr package ?

Comment: I am using subfiles package.

Comment: You could do something similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358429/36296

Comment: I just reread your question... you want to `\cite{}` a reference using bibtex ? or do you want to reference something like a figure with `\ref{}` ? if it is the latter I suggest you look into xr. If  it is the first, then do you want each chapter to have its own bibliography ?  a MWE would be helpful here...

Comment: @EladDen I want to \cite{} a reference so that it can show up in my subfile after compiling, or even better, listed as a reference at the end of the subfile.

Comment: If you want to use real literature references from other files, you should use the `xcite` package, which extends the citing mechanism 'the same way' (well ;-)) like `xr` does for the real cross-references