# How to make bibliography to work in subfiles of a subfile?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, conditionals, subfiles

I am writing a long report that needs the help of the subfiles package to break it into individual sections. It works like a charm until I further split one of the subfiles into two. Previously, the `\ifSubfilesClassLoaded` command helps distinguish whether a given file is compiled from main or subfiles shown in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107064/bibliographies-when-using-subfiles). But when I get two levels of subfiles, it can no longer tell which level of subfiles it is working on.

Consider a hierarchy of files like this:

```
main.tex
myBib.bib
sections/section1.tex
materials/a_complex_table.tex
```

Here is a MWE:

```
%%%%%% main.tex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
    \section{Section One}
    \subfile{sections/section1.tex}
    
    \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
    \bibliography{myBib}
\end{document}

%%%%%% section1.tex
% !TeX root = section1.tex
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
    I like to cite \cite{A}
    
    \subfile{../materials/a_complex_table.tex}
    
    \ifSubfilesClassLoaded{
        \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
        \bibliography{../myBib}
    }{}
\end{document}

%%%%%% a_complex_table.tex
% !TeX root = a_complex_table.tex
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htb]
        \begin{tabular}{ l r }
            Name & Reference \\
            A    & \cite{A}  \\
            B    & \cite{B}  \\
            G    & \cite{G}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \ifSubfilesClassLoaded{
        \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
        \bibliography{../myBib}
    }{}
\end{document}
```

and my bibfile:

```
@book{A,
    title={The meaning of A},
    author={A. Alpha},
    year=2020,
    publisher={Apublisher}
}
@book{B,
    title={The meaning of B},
    author={B. Beta},
    year=2021,
    publisher={Bpublisher}
}
@book{G,
    title={The meaning of G},
    author={G. Gamma},
    year=2022,
    publisher={Gpublisher}
}
```

Typesetting `main.tex` and `a_complex_table.tex` both are fine, but compiling my `section1.tex` executes `\bibliography{../myBib}` twice since `\ifSubfilesClassLoaded` doesn't distinguish between subfiles. How can I fix this duplication?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: For future reference: when preparing MWEs, please avoid unnecessary directory structures. You are just making extra busy work for people who are trying to help you.

Comment: @WillieWong In fact, it is helpful, and necessary, to provide a MWE with a directory structure similar to the full project. This way we can test that TeX and especially BibTeX finds all files, no matter which file is compiled. With the search mechanics and expansion mechanisms involved, I'd never claim that a solution works by testing it just with all files in the same directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your goal is to print the **complete** bibliography at the end of every subfile, a simpler thing to do is the following:

1. Remove all `\biblio...` and `\IfSubfil...` commands from your current files.
2. Change the `main.tex` file to read

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} % <===== new
\AtEndDocument{\bibliography{myBib}}  % <=== new

\begin{document}
    \section{Section One}
    \subfile{sections/section1.tex}
    
\end{document}
```

3. For building the subfiles, one has to do one thing extra when using `bibtex`. Either:

   - Run `bibtex` from the main folder: so `bibtex sections/section1`
   - Or add the main folder to the search path when running `bibtex` , so from within the folder `sections/` you can run `BIBINPUTS=../ bibtex section1`.

*Explanation*:

- By putting `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}` in the preamble, it is automatically propagated to all subfiles.
- The `\AtEndDoc...` is likewise propagated to each subfile when they are compiled as a standalone document, but will be run only once for each compile.

Comment: This answer assumes that the bibliography is the final thing to be printed. If that's not the case, the other answer is more flexible.

Comment: Your approach works fine, if all files are in the same directory. In this case one has to run `bibtex` also on the subfiles, since this is how the `bbl` files for the sufiles are generated. However, if the files are distributed over subdirectories, like in the OP's setting, your approach does not seem to work. How do you obtain the `bbl` files for the subfiles? When latexing, say, `section1.tex`, TeX tries to load `section1.bbl`, not `main.bbl`.

Comment: @gernot : oops, I had some leftover files that influenced the process. **But** I've also found a correct work-flow that would work. Let me edit to include the correct list of steps.

Answer (score 4):

- In the main file, add the line

  ```
  \usepackage{xstring}
  ```
- In the subfiles, replace `\ifSubfilesClassLoaded` by `\IfStrEq*{\jobname}{filename}`, where `filename` is the name of the subfile (without `.tex`).

As an example, `sections/section1.tex` becomes

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
    I like to cite \cite{A}
    
    \subfile{../materials/a_complex_table.tex}
    
    \IfStrEq*{\jobname}{section1}{
        \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}% <<< will apply to all subfiles if moved to the preamble of the main file, no need to repeat it
        \bibliography{../myBib}
    }{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As a side comment: I would also just load `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}` in the **preamble** of the `main.tex` (before `\begin{document}`) so it is automatically propagated to all the subfiles.

Comment: @WillieWong Sure, if the bibliography style is the same everywhere, it is better to put the command into the preamble of the main file.